# Use delta and epsilon to prove the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove, using the epsilon-delta definiton, the following limit exists：

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\sqrt{4 - x}} = 2$$

Comment: What exactly do you want to show here? Do you want to show that the square root is continuous or that the statement above holds using that fact?

Comment: I want to show that there exists such a delta which makes the above statement hold. So, I will need to have something like delta = (an expression containing epsilon) and use it to prove that when  |x| < delta, |sqrt(4-x) - 2| < epsilon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $|\sqrt{4-x}-2|=|\frac{(4-x)-4}{\sqrt{4-x}+2}|\leq\frac{|x|}{2}$. If $|x|<2\varepsilon$, then we get the convergence as $|\sqrt{4-x}-2|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!